# Sorting and diff of CSV file using bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, unix

I am trying to compare two sorted csv files:

```sh
for filename in `ls "$1"/dev`
do
  dev_file="$1/dev/$filename"
  ccu_file="$1/ccu/$filename "
  echo "diff of $dev_file ...and......$ccu_file"
  result=$(diff <(sort $dev_file) <(sort $ccu_file ))
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "files are the same"
  else
        echo "files are different"
        echo "$result"
  fi
done
```

It seems, there is syntax ERROR:

```
test.sh: command substitution: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: command substitution: line 6: `diff <(sort $dev_file) <(sort $ccu_file )'
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two files like this:

```
if cmp -s file1.csv file2.csv; then
    echo files are identical
else
    echo files are different
fi
```

From your script, it looks like you want to compare each csv file in `dev/` with the same name file in `ccu/`. You can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "${1:?}/dev" && [[ -d ../ccu ]] || exit 1

for i in *.csv; do
    if [[ -e ../ccu/"$i" ]]; then
        if cmp -s "$i" ../ccu/"$i"; then
            echo files "$i" and ../ccu/"$i" are identical
        else
            echo files "$i" and ../ccu/"$i" are different
        fi
    else
         echo "../ccu/$i: not found" >&2
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks @dan. How I can sort both files before comparing ?

Comment: @dev you can use process substitution like in your post (`<("$i")`). This compares the files in sorted form, but it doesn’t edit the file on disk. If you want to sort the file and save it (before comparing) you can do something like: `sort "$i" > "$i".ed && mv "$i".ed "$i"`, or use a temp file instead of `"$i".ed` (look at `mktemp`, and `trap` to remove it at exit).